# How can I focus the interview on what I'm good at?

Tags: resume, career-development, hiring-process

In my resume, I mentioned familiarity with Java and PHP, and basic knowledge in C and C++. Why would an interviewer expect one to be familiar with C first?

I just studied C in my college and I haven't practiced. When it comes to Java, I have solved some problems in coding bat, and also some mini web applications in PHP
(not appropriate to mention).

I want the interviewer to ask more questions from Java & PHP. But how he would see this? How can I make the interview focus on what I am good at?

Comment: Side note: don't mention something in your resume unless you're okay doing that as your primary function. If you don't want to do C/C++ programming, don't even mention you have heard of it.

Comment: If the employer is looking for a C/C++ programmer, your Java and PHP isn't interesting. What is the predominate language used by the employer?

Comment: This question does not ask what job to take or skills to learn it simply asks how to focus the interview on the skills the op is good at.  This is a great question and I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply for jobs where the primary skills required are the skills you are good at.

Typically interviewers focus on the skills that are important to the position you are appling for.  If the position you are applying for requires C or C++ skills then I really do not care about your Java and PHP abilities.

On the flip side if my primary concern is your PHP and/or Java skills I am not likely to ask you much about C.  However if you have the skill listed on your resume and I ask you a simple question about it and you can not answer, I may probe to see if maybe you are padding your resume with skills you do not have.  This could be a red flag because if you falsify one thing what else is false on your resume?  Generally if I find a candidate has been dishonest on their resume I recommend against hiring them.  Your resume is a reflection of you; if you feel the need to lie about yourself then I generally prefer not to work with you.

Comment: whether it is expected from computer student to be familiar with c by default

Comment: @User13025 - If you are applying for a job doing C yes.  If you have C listed on your resume as a skill then yes.  If it is not on your resume and the Job does not require C then I am not going to ask you questions about C.

Answer (score 9):

#### You put it on there I am going to grill you on it ...

you put it on there, expect it to be challenged on it, putting something on your resume is a invitation to be asked about it in detail.

#### Plain and simple, don't put anything that isn't relevant on your resume.

No matter how much you think it will add, if I didn't mention it in the requirements I don't care about it.

#### Fail a simple question about something and you fail the entire interview

If you put something on there as filler, and I ask you a simple question on it and and you fail, I probably won't even ask you about the relevant stuff figuring you have already wasted my time with mis-representation already.

#### This has been covered ad-nasuem on this site, the internet and well before the internet in books about resume writing.

It should be common knowledge/sense by now that you only put what is relevant and be as specific and brief about how it is relevant to the position, anything else will be ignored or worse count against you.

Put yourself in the position of reviewing, hundreds of resumes for a single position, and then read your resume, you have about 15 - 30 seconds to make the cut to get into the *will consider* pile.

Comment: Your having half of your answer bolded is distracting and basically is a cue to ignore the rest of your answer.  You might want to limit the bolding to a key phrase or two.

Comment: I disagree, Chad - I think each of those bolded phrases are very, very important.

Comment: @corsiKlauseHoHoHo - There are other ways to communicate that besides bold face.  I am not saying they are not important just that the formatting of this answer could be greatly improved.